# what's wrong with this simple regex in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, regex

It's a simple regex and I've tried using a few of the online testing tools and it works but when I run it in code, it doesn't.

**BEGIN EDIT**: It doesn't find any match at all. What I am trying to do is check if a line in a configuration file contains the `http` setting. So if a line is `extraintf=` I want to change it to `extraintf=http`, if the line is `extraintf=rc:ncurses`, I want to change it to `extraintf=rc:ncurses:http`, and if the line is `#extraintf=` I want to change it to `extraintf=http`. I am using a regex to find the location and length of that line, once I have the start and length of the line I wrote some tested and working code that will do the above fine, it's just finding the range of the match that is the problem. **END EDIT**

Here's my regex:

```
^#?extraintf=.*$
```

I want it find the middle line in all of these files:

File1:

```
# Interface module (string)
#intf=

# Extra interface modules (string)
extraintf=                                    //match this line

# Control interfaces (string)
#control=
```

File 2:

```
# Interface module (string)
#intf=

# Extra interface modules (string)
extraintf=rc                                    //match this line

# Control interfaces (string)
#control=
```

File 3:

```
# Interface module (string)
#intf=

# Extra interface modules (string)
#extraintf=                                    //match this line

# Control interfaces (string)
#control=
```

And then the way I check for a match is using:

```
//check if file exists
BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:fullPath isDirectory:&isDirectory];

if (isDirectory || !fileExists) {
    return;
}

//get the settings file
NSError *error;
NSString *settingsString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:fullPath encoding:NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding error:&error];


NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"^#?extraintf=.*$" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:NULL];

NSRange rangeOfFirstMatch = [regex rangeOfFirstMatchInString:settingsString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [settingsString length])];

if (!NSEqualRanges(rangeOfFirstMatch, NSMakeRange(NSNotFound, 0))) {
    //got a match
}
else {
    //no match
}
```

Comment: is this: `regularExpressionWithPattern:@"^extraintf=$"` correct in the code you pasted? it is missing the `#` and the `.*`... furthermore, could you explain what is not working? no match at all? just in one of the cases?

Comment: Sorry, I copy paster the code I was testing with, fixed now. It doesn't find any match at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `NSRegularExpressionAnchorsMatchLines` to the options. This will allow `^` and `$` to match the start and end of lines.

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"^#?extraintf=.*$" 
                              options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive|NSRegularExpressionAnchorsMatchLines 
                              error:NULL];
```

Comment: i had the same issue and tried ur approach but it doesn't work.. although in my case the regular expression string is different.
its

 NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+(?:[A-Z]{2}|com|org|net|edu|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|asia|jobs|museum)" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive|NSRegularExpressionAnchorsMatchLines error:&error];

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried loosening the match like this?

```
"^[^e]?extraintf=.*$"
```

Comment: Tried `^\#?extraintf=.*$` which gives me a "invalid escape sequence" warning, and tried `^\\#?extraintf=.*$` which doesn't give a warning but doesn't work.

Comment: you are right about the double escape! could you try my second suggestion? apart from this, everything seems correct to me. are you sure that `settingsString` is correctly initialized?